# restlet syntax for jersey version 1 request list of objects

Tags: java, jersey, restlet

I am trying to convert the following jersey code to restlet.

```
WebResource webResource = client.resource("/getlistofobjects");
List<MyObject> thisMemberObjects = webResource
    .accept("application/json")
    .get(new GenericType<List<MyObject>>(){});

thisListOfObjects.addAll((List<MyObject>)thisMemberObjects);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create an annotated interface, as described below:

```
public interface MyService {
    @Get
    List<MyObject> getObjs();
}
```

Then you can leverage Restlet converter from class `ClientResource` based on this interface with code like this:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://.../getlistofobjects");
cr.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
MyService myService = cr.wrap(MyService.class);
List<MyObject> objs = myService.getObjs();
```

Don't forget to add in your classpath the extension `org.restlet.ext.jackson` that will automatically convert the JSON content to Java objects.

Here a sample `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.restlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>test.restlet.client</artifactId>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-snapshot</version>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <restlet-version>2.3.1</restlet-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-restlet</id>
            <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.restlet.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

**Edited**

For the following response payload:

```
{
    "elitFileBasic": [
        {
            "application":"$TRACKING",
            "fileName":"FILE.TRACKING.DATA"
        },
        {
            "application":"$TRACKING$",
            "fileName":"TRACKING.EVENT.5"
        }
    ]
}
```

You need to have the following bean:

```
public class ResponseBean {
    private List<ResponseElementBean> elitFileBasic;

    public List<ResponseElementBean> getElitFileBasic() {
        return this.elitFileBasic;
    }

    public void setElitFileBasic(List<ResponseElementBean> elitFileBasic) {
        this.elitFileBasic = elitFileBasic;
    }
}

public class ResponseElementBean {
    private String application;
    private fileName;

    // Getters and setters
    (...)
}
```

In this case, the annotated interface would be:

```
public interface MyService {
    @Get
    ResponseBean getObjs();
}
```

You can notice that you can update response deserialization with Jackson to support a list of objects as return of the method `getObjs`. For such use case, you need to register a custom deserializer. This answer can give you some interesting hints: [Restlet Complex Object to XML serializaton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781737/restlet-complex-object-to-xml-serializaton/28782606#28782606).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: now getting an exception - com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@1a1d6a08; line: 1, column: 1] @thierry templier

Comment: Could you provide a sample of data structure that is received? Thanks! This would help me to understand the exception...

Comment: {"elitFileBasic":[{"application":"$TRACKING","fileName":"FILE.TRACKING.DATA"},
                  {"application":"$TRACKING$","fileName":"TRACKING.EVENT.5"}
]}

Comment: prior comment is the json structure received by a restlet client from a Jersey server @thierry templier

Comment: I updated my answer with the response content you gave me in your comment... Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks - the updated content solved my issue. I did have to make sure the ResponseBean and ResponseElementBean were defined "static" (found this in other overflow entries). I do have another question. Why do I see ----  text text/csv csv vs application application/json json
application application/json json vs text text/csv csv
isCompatible false
isCompatible true ---- messages in my log? @thierry

Comment: Yes, in fact, Restlet let you the choice to work either on raw data or beans. Where do you see these hints displayed? It seems to be media types in fact. Otherwise feel free to upvote my answer or even accept it if it suits you ;-) Thanks!