# Restlet converts JSON to LinkedHashMap instead of List<MyObject>?

Tags: java, json, restlet, restlet-2.0

This is what my `Rest` endpoint looks like

```
  @Post("json")
  public List<LogProcessorExpression> addLogProcessorExpression(
      final List<LogProcessorExpression> expressions) throws LPRestletException {
    if (expressions == null || expressions.isEmpty()) {
      return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    final Integer currentTenantId = Utils.getCurrentTenantId(getRequest());
    return customAttributesManager.addLogProcessorExpression(currentTenantId, expressions);
  }
```

the method it calls looks like

```
List<LogProcessorExpression> addLogProcessorExpression(final Integer currentTenantId,
                                                       final List<LogProcessorExpression> expressions)
      throws LPRestletException {
    final Map<String, LogProcessorExpression> cache = getCacheByCustomAttributeName(expressions);
    try {
      final List<Customattributesmetadata> cams =
          getCustomAttributesMetaDataForTenant(currentTenantId);

      for (final Customattributesmetadata metadata : cams) {
        if (cache.containsKey(metadata.getAttributecolumnname())) {
          metadata.setLogprocessorexpression(
              cache.get(metadata.getAttributecolumnname()).toString());
        }
        metadata.save();
      }
    } catch (final TorqueException e) {
      final String error = "Failed to update LogExpression custom attributes";
      LOGGER.error(error, e);
      throw new LPRestletException(error, e);
    }

    return expressions;
  }
```

which calls to other methods in chain. what I realized when accessing this endpoint as

```
 curl -v -H "Authorization:Basic Y3VyYasqrwqrjQGdtYWlsLmNvbTp0YXAzYWg=" \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '[{"source": "ad", "attributePrefix": "ad_", "attributeName": "department"}]' \
     http://172.11.041.240:8080/api/rest/msp/attributes
```

That it returns

```
{
   "code" : 500
   "message" : "The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request",
}
```

When I looked at the logs, I see lines as

```
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.shn.api.dto.LogProcessorExpression
        at com.shn.api.restlet.logprocessor.CustomAttributesManager.getCacheByCustomAttributeName(CustomAttributesManager.java:55)
        at com.shn.api.restlet.logprocessor.CustomAttributesManager.addLogProcessorExpression(CustomAttributesManager.java:24)
        at com.shn.api.restlet.logprocessor.CustomAttributeMetadataRestlet.addLogProcessorExpression(CustomAttributeMetadataRestlet.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:521)
        ... 67 more
```

**Question**
- Why is it not casting them to `List<LogProcessorExpression>`?
- What do I need to do to fix it?

**UPDATE**

**Line 24** looks like

```
final Map<String, LogProcessorExpression> cache = getCacheByCustomAttributeName(expressions);
```

**Line 44** looks like

```
return customAttributesManager.addLogProcessorExpression(currentTenantId, expressions);
```

`getCacheByCustomAttributeName(expressions)` looks like

```
  Map<String, LogProcessorExpression> getCacheByCustomAttributeName(
      final List<LogProcessorExpression> expressions) {
    if (expressions == null || expressions.isEmpty()) {
      return Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    final Map<String, LogProcessorExpression> attributeByExpression = new HashMap<>();
    for (final LogProcessorExpression expression : expressions) {
      attributeByExpression.put(expression.getAttributeName(), expression);
    }
    return attributeByExpression;
  }
```

Comment: what is return type of this addLogProcessorExpression method

Comment: Just updated, thanks

Comment: add line number 24 and 44

Comment: done, everything you needed

Comment: I guess my `DTO` needs to implement  `Serializable`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think restlet might not be sophisticated enough to extract the parameterized type `List<LogProcessorExpression>` from your handler method's parameter list.

```
@Post("json")
public List<LogProcessorExpression> addLogProcessorExpression(
  final List<LogProcessorExpression> expressions)
```

It just takes `List` and presumably uses that when deserializing (with Jackson). Jackson uses `LinkedHashMap` as a deserialization target type when one isn't provided.

Short of restlet implementing this better (maybe in a newer version?), a potential solution is to define a custom type

```
class LogProcessorExpressionList extends ArrayList<LogProcessorExpression> {}
```

and using that type as the parameter type

```
@Post("json")
public List<LogProcessorExpression> addLogProcessorExpression(
  final LogProcessorExpressionList expressions)
```

Jackson can then extract the parameterized super type of the type `LogProcessorExpressionList`, which is `ArrayList<LogProcessorExpression>`, from which it can extract `LogProcessorExpression` as the target element type.

Comment: Interesting, now I see `{"code":422,"message":"The server understands the content type of the request entity and the syntax of the request entity is correct but was unable to process the contained instructions"}`

Comment: I needed Getters/Setters and empty Constructor for `LogProcessorExpression` and that solved the problem with your solution

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps could you use a custom Jackson deserializer for this? See this link for this feature: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization.

This answer gives you some hints to configuration the Jackson `ObjectMapper`: [How to register Jackson Jdk8 module in Restlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303473/how-to-register-jackson-jdk8-module-in-restlet). This allows to register the custom deserializer and have the hand on the deserialization processing to create the right object within your list.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me..

```
class LogProcessorExpressionList extends ArrayList<LogProcessorExpression> {}
```